# Access Airport signal data

Tags: terminal, wifi, airport

I want to be able to write the current list of Wifi networks in airport, and their respective strengths, to a file. I would like to use some sort of bash script to do this, but I am unsure how to access the data in Airport.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Open Terminal.app and enter:

```
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/airport -I
```

You have to be connected to a wireless signal. The output will look similar to the following:

```
     agrCtlRSSI: -64
     agrExtRSSI: 0
    agrCtlNoise: -91
    agrExtNoise: 0
          state: running
        op mode: station 
     lastTxRate: 130
        maxRate: 144
lastAssocStatus: 0
    802.11 auth: open
      link auth: wpa2-psk
          BSSID: 28:cf:da:b1:6:77
           SSID: 
            MCS: 15
        channel: 6
```

Most of the data is self explanatory. `agrCtlRSSI` is the signal strength; the closer it is to `0`, the stronger the signal. `agrCtlNoise` is the noise on your Wi-Fi signal; you want this as low as possible. Finally, `maxRate` is the maximum rate at which your Wi-Fi signal can run at, and `lastTxRate` is the last transmitted rate.

You can also use this Terminal command to scan the airwaves for other Wi-Fi signals to connect to (I believe this is what you were looking for):

```
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/airport -s
```

This returns something like:

```
            SSID BSSID             RSSI CHANNEL HT CC SECURITY (auth/unicast/group)
             28:cf:da:b1:06:78 -73  100,+1  Y  GB WPA2(PSK/AES/AES) 
           dlink 00:19:5b:de:4e:36 -90  6       N  -- WEP
    FON_BELGACOM 06:19:70:1e:c3:6e -77  1       N  BE NONE
      bbox2-f279 00:19:70:1e:c3:6e -77  1       N  BE WEP
   telenet-6F8E6 5c:35:3b:1e:88:20 -91  11      Y  -- WPA(PSK/TKIP,AES/TKIP) WPA2(PSK/TKIP,AES/TKIP) 
             28:cf:da:b1:06:77 -65  6       Y  GB WPA2(PSK/AES/AES)
```

If you’ll be using these commands a lot, you might want to add `/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/Current/Resources` to your `$PATH`, like this:

```
# Place this in your `~/.bash_profile`
export PATH="/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/Current/Resources:$PATH"
```

That way, you can simply use the `airport` command without typing the full path to the binary every time:

```
airport -I
airport -s
```

[Source](http://www.mactricksandtips.com/2010/06/use-terminal-to-measure-wi-fi-strength.html)

Comment: Wow very in depth, detailed answer. I'll get back to you once I try it out, thanks a ton man!

Comment: Hi Mathias, I did click accepted, not sure why it didn't register as that before!